# Method 'Handle' cannot implement method from interface 'MediatR.IRequestHandler

Tags: .net, mediatr

i am trying to create a "create" api endpoint in .net following a tutorial. following code should work but it is not.

getting this error:

```
 error CS0738: 'Create.Handler' does not implement interface member 'IRequestHandler<Create.Command>.Handle
(Create.Command, CancellationToken)'. 'Create.Handler.Handle(Create.Command, CancellationToken)' cannot implement 'IRequestHandler<Create.Command>.Handle(Create.Command, CancellationToken)' because i
t does not have the matching return type of 'Task'
```

```
using Domain;
using MediatR;
using Persistence;

namespace Application.Activities;

public class Create
{
    public class Command : IRequest
    {
        public Activity Activity { get; set; }
    }

    public class Handler : IRequestHandler<Command>
    {
        private readonly DataContext _context;

        public Handler(DataContext context)
        {
            _context = context;
        }

        public async Task<Unit> Handle(Command request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
        {
            _context.Activities.Add(request.Activity);
            await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
            return Unit.Value;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

This is possibly a change since Mediator 12 (Feb 23). You don't need to specify a return type.

[Changing IRequest to just be a normal Task instead of Task](https://github.com/jbogard/MediatR/pull/835)

Before:

```
public async Task<Unit> Handle(Command request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        _context.Activities.Add(request.Activity);
        await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
        return Unit.Value;
    }
```

After:

```
 public async Task Handle(Command request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        _context.Activities.Add(request.Activity);
        await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

This error is showing because you are not explicitly telling MediatR the return type of your handler and your command. It depends on the data type of Unit.Value variable. Supposing that it's a string try this:

```
public class Create
{
  public class Command : IRequest<string>
 {
    public Activity Activity { get; set; }
 }

public class Handler : IRequestHandler<Command, string>
{
    private readonly DataContext _context;

    public Handler(DataContext context)
    {
        _context = context;
    }

    public async Task<string> Handle(Command request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        _context.Activities.Add(request.Activity);
        await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
        return Unit.Value;
    }
  }
}
```